# Tailwind DaisyUI with MUI

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, tailwind-css, daisyui, mui-x-date-picker

I'm using TW and DaisyUI as my main UI lib, but DaisyUI does not have DatePicker and MUI has a really nice one. In DaisyUI i'm using their color standarts like `bg-primary`

How can i add `bg-primary` to MUI date picker?

```
          <MuiDatePicker
            onOpen={() => {
              console.log('open');
            }}
            sx={{
              width: '100%',
              '& .MuiInputBase-root': {
                backgroundColor: '',
              },
            }}
          />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`bg-primary` is coming from Tailwind, right? If so, you should be able to follow the [Tailwind CSS setup guide](https://mui.com/material-ui/guides/interoperability/#tailwind-css) in the Material UI docs to start adding Tailwind `className`s directly to the MUI X Date Picker.

Comment: missed this one that worked thank you